# Continuous Touching on a ccMenuItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am creating a program with cocos2d where I have 2 ccMenuItems each linked to an image: In this case, one is a left arrow, the other is a right arrow. I also have an image in the center of my view that will rotate depending on the arrow pressed.

When I put my finger on one of the two menu items, either left or right, I want the center image to rotate as long as my finger is on the button. That is where I got lost. I tried using the following code:

```
- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(leftArrow, p) || CGRectContainsPoint(rightArrow, p)) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

- (void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(leftArrow, p)) {
        [gun runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:0.2 angle:180]]];
    }
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(rightArrow, p)) {
        [gun runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:0.2 angle:0]]];

    }

}
```

Using this code, when I press on one of the two menu items, the ccTouchBegan method isn't even called. The method is only called when I touch elsewhere.

How do I work with continuous actions when holding down a ccMenuItem.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, two methods you posted are in your CCLayer's subclass.

First of all, if you want to handle touches by yourself, you must remove menu items. CCMenu has much more touch priority and if it handles that the touch hit any menu item, it will swallow it. Thats why you receive touches only when touch is outside menu items.

The second one, what is `leftArrow` and `rightArrow`? Rects of your arrows?

And as for me, in such case I can propose you to run update method and change `rotation` property of your center image in it on every tick. I mean, that rotation value will be 0 if no one arraw was touched and will have positive or negative value due to the arrow you touched.

Comment: Yes, the leftArrow and rightArrow are Rects of my arrow images.
If I can't use CCMenu, what do I use? Sprites?

Comment: at the moment you do not have to use anything at all. you have two rects and layer for handling touches. in this case you just need two arrow sprites to mark place to touch.

Answer (score 2):

You have to subclass CCMenuItem to get such behaviour:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

@interface RepeatMenuItem : CCMenuItemSprite 
{
    CGFloat speed;
}

@end
```

And implementation:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// RepeatMenuItem
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark RepeatMenuItem

@implementation RepeatMenuItem


-(void) selected
{
    [super selected];
    block_(self);
    speed = 0.8;
    [self schedule:@selector(repeatEvent:) interval:speed];
}


-(void) unselected
{
    [self unschedule:@selector(repeatEvent:)];
    [super unselected];
}


-(void) activate
{
}


-(void) repeatEvent:(id)sender
{
    CGFloat minSpeed = 0.05;

    if (speed > minSpeed)
        speed = speed/3;
    if (speed < minSpeed)
        speed = minSpeed;

    [self unschedule:@selector(repeatEvent:)];
    block_(self);
    [self schedule:@selector(repeatEvent:) interval:speed];
}

@end
```

Comment: subclassing CCMenuItem is not a good solution as it allows simple button to know about speed, that is not needed to the button.

Comment: Speed is just repeat interval. used for repeat event frequency, like key in keyboard. Anyway topic caster should change something to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the CCMenuItemWhatever class you are using for these menu items, and override the 'selected' and 'unselected' methods. The menu grabs the touches (ie IT answers YES on its own ccTouchBegan function, thus the touch dispatcher does not propagate it to you).

```
-(void) selected{
    [super selected];
    // start your animation here
}

-(void) unselected {
    [super unselected];
    // stop your animation here.
}
```